# How to download different versions of a repository's snapshots from GitHub?

Tags: git, netbeans, github

I want to analyze and format a report on changes made through the entire versions of any Java specific repository.

But I'm not able to find older versions of a repository, i.e snapshots, so that I may compare them with latest commit and analyze the changes made.

EDIT:
I want to compare the snapshots using the NetBeans IDE.

Comment: the thing that hangs up most people who are new to Git is that there aren't separate directories for the 'snapshots' (which in git is essentially every commit|branch|tag|SHA). Git changes the working root directory contents to correspond to where you want the HEAD to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

When you clone a Git repository, ***you get all the snapshots/commits*** for that repository, by default. Just clone a local repo like so:

```
git clone <url-or-path-to-remote-repo>
```

You can then compare different snapshots/commits/tags using `git diff`

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2>
git diff <tag1> <tag2>
git diff <tag1> <commit2>
# Etc...
```

Alternatively, you can switch to a particular tag and get all files matching that version. You will get the repository's snapshots of what you need like this :

```
git checkout <tag1>
git checkout <commit2>
```

Comment: How to use Diff in NetBeans for comparing snapshots?